# Icon get disappeared after hover in css

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am working on Angular JS (1.x) and my requirement is that I need to show tooltip text upon hovering on info icon.
Tooltip text appears perfectly well. But the problem is that icon gets disappeared when I hover on that. Once I stop hover then icon again gets appeared.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 margin-left-26">            
    <span ng-show="{{ job.information }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign
    spark-error-info pad-left-10" tooltip="{{job.information.sparkJob}}">
    </span>
</div>
```

And here comes my CSS:

```
.spark-error-info:hover:after{
      content: attr(tooltip);
      padding: 4px 8px;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      margin-top:10px;
      top: 100%;
      z-index: 20;
      white-space: nowrap;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #000000;
}

.spark-error-info:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    border-width: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    top: 0px;
    content: "";
    left: 97%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the JsFiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/gLt86eqe/4/

Comment: can you post a fiddle with the issue?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gLt86eqe/2/

Comment: did you check is this fiddle working?? is it able to reproduce your issue??

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal: Actually I never created fiddle.. This is the first time m creating. Its not reproducing anything..thats what I am trying to figure out..

Comment: Now it is working @SaurabhAgrawal
https://jsfiddle.net/gLt86eqe/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The `.glyphicon` icon requires the *pseudo-element* `:before` to render the icon using the `content` property.

This `content` property value (for the `.glyphicon` icon) is being overwritten on the `:hover` state, with the tooltip `content` property intended to draw the arrow, see below:

**Natural Element State:**

```
.glyphicon-info-sign:before {
    content: "\e086";
}
```

**`:hover` Element State:**

```
.spark-error-info:hover:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    border-width: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    top: 0px;
    /* refrain from re-declaring the `content` property value as an empty string */
    /* content: ""; */ 
    left: 97%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

The selectors are different but both rules match and will apply to the same element.

### Solution

Consider nesting another element within the `span` element of the `.glyphicon` icon.

Another empty `span` element could be used *specifically* for tooltips - using this approach you separate your concerns.

**Html Example:**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign
    spark-error-info pad-left-10">
   <span class="icon-tooltip" tooltip="Hello this is my fiddle"></span>
</span>
```

**CSS Example:**

Then adjust your contextual css selectors accordingly for the given state changes...

```
.spark-error-info:hover .icon-tooltip:after { ... }

.spark-error-info:hover .icon-tooltip:before { ... }
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.spark-error-info:hover .icon-tooltip:after {
  content: attr(tooltip);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.spark-error-info:hover .icon-tooltip:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #000 transparent;
  border-width: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  top: 0px;
  content: ""; 
  left: 97%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}

.margin-left-26 {
  margin-left: 26px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 margin-left-26">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign
    spark-error-info pad-left-10">
      <span class="icon-tooltip" tooltip="Hello this is my fiddle"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```